# applying a function across rows in dataframe

Tags: r, matrix, apply, rows

I have a dataset of approximate counts of birds of 5 species. I wrote a function to calculate the diversity of species using Broullions Index. My data looks like this and my function is written like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
sp1 = c(2, 3, 4, 5),         
sp2 = c(1, 6, 7, 2),
sp3 = c(1, 9, 4, 3),
sp4 = c(2, 2, 2, 4),
sp5 = c(3, 3, 2, 1),
treatment1 = c("A", "B", "C", "A"),
treatment2 = c("D", "E", "D", "E")
)

#write function that estimates Broullion's Index
Brillouin_Index <- function(x){  
  N <- sum(x)
 (log10(factorial(N)) - sum(log10(factorial(x)))) / N
}

df2 <- df %>%
   mutate(bindex = Brillon_Index(matrix(df[1:5,])
```

How do apply my function to calculate the Broullions Index across rows? I thought something like the above would work but no luck yet. The point would be to use the diversity index as the response variable in relation to treatment 1 and 2 which is why I'd like to sum across rows and get a single value across for each row for a new variable called `bindex`. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Best,

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm not used to having to do this and am only now learning the functionality of `apply` . The second and third example worked perfectly but I did get an error for the solution in `dplyr`. Error mentions that `c_across()` can only be used inside dplyr verbs. Error in (function (cond)  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': `c_across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: Can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')` if you are using an old version of dplyr, it may not work.  Thanks.  I used `1.0.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rowwise` to group by row

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(bindex = Brillouin_Index(as.matrix(c_across(1:5)))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 4 x 8
#    sp1   sp2   sp3   sp4   sp5 treatment1 treatment2 bindex
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>
#1     2     1     1     2     3 A          D           0.464
#2     3     6     9     2     3 B          E           0.528
#3     4     7     4     2     2 C          D           0.527
#4     5     2     3     4     1 A          E           0.505
```

---

Or use `apply` in `base R`

```
df$bindex <- apply(df[1:5], 1, Brillouin_Index)
df$bindex
#[1] 0.4643946 0.5277420 0.5273780 0.5051951
```

---

Or with `dapply` in `collapse`

```
library(collapse
df$bindex <- dapply(slt(df, 1:4), Brillouin_Index, MARGIN = 1)
```